# Puppeteer: How do I intercept requests across multiple "pages"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am attempting to download PDF's from a webpage where there are multiple PDF links on a single page. The first issue is that when click()-ing the links it automatically brings up a new tab or page. I've researched this a ton - and the behavior seems to be inherent - and unchangeable. So - my next route to buffering in all this content is to set a request-interceptor that takes every similar request (with exception of a URL parameter that changes) and using the browser cookies - copy the request and send it using a different request library.

This brings me to my main question - what is the best way to set a every new page to basically "hook" into my request interceptor when upon it's creation? I've already looked at the requests going out of my primary page - and it seems that it's within the NEW tabs where the request is sent.

Anybody know how this would be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [targetcreated](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#event-targetcreated) event emitted by the browser.

One important thing for you to know is that, although a new target will be created, a PDF will be open by the PDF viewer (if available). You won't be able to `evaluate`, `screenshot`, or `pdf` that target.

```js
const browser =  await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false});
const page = await browser.newPage();

browser.on('targetcreated', e => {
    console.log(e.url());
});

await page.goto("https://codepen.io/hardkoded/pen/gOYmVww");
const frameEl = await page.$("#result");
const frame = await frameEl.contentFrame();
await frame.click("a");
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, definitely helpful and good to know. So that's pretty much the issue. The PDF opens into an <imbed > link on a new tab, so in the viewer. Before I was trying to listen for popups  to get the url. Since I know navigating to URL in my normal chrome browser will download the pdf. So you don't know of any explicit way to disable the PDF viewer or somehow bypass it? Or are you saying that's not possible?

Comment: There is no bulletproof option yet. See this issue https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/299